# SOAP call execution time measurement difference between server logs and my client

Tags: python, api, iis, soap, sentry

I'm writing a client for a specific SOAP API. I'm getting huge execution times and therefore contacted API owner who told me this:

> The average duration calls of GetPrices calls calculated from two
>   sources which store the duration of the calls show a average duration
>   throughout the 5 days that punter was calling our system of just over
>   25 millseconds which matches the average of most punters during the
>   same time period . The two sources are the Sentry Logs which
>   calculates the duration of the calls between all the application
>   components and the Time taken from the IISLogs which includes the
>   transport time from our API server to the punters calling machine .

For the exact same 5 days for the same GetPrices call I was averaging 0.08-0.1s which is 4 times longer than server logs show.

What could be possibly the reason for such high difference between my measurements and API owner's measurements ?

The way I measure my execution time is very simple:

```
start_time = time.time()
# GetPrices call
end_time = time.time() - start_time
```

Please let me know if there's anything else I could provide.

Comment: You are not just measuring server response time, but also the time it takes your soap library to parse the response and convert it to relevant objects. Which library are you using?

Comment: @jordanm I'm using python suds library. Response returned by this GetPrices is barely 11477 bytes which is 0.01mb. I doubt parsing has this much effect on execution time. Or does it ?

Comment: You can use a profiler to determine where most execution time is spent. I had a project many years ago where soap calls took a very long time to process, but later discovered it was an inefficiency in the library we were using (python-zsi). A switch to suds gave us a huge boost in performance.

Comment: @jordanm I've measured execution time line by line and 98% of the execution time is spent on this line which is the actual call to the server:

resp = self.client.service["SecureService"].PlaceOrdersWithReceipt(obj)

Do you have any idea why I and API owner measure such different execution times ?

Comment: This still includes the time it takes to build the xml document to post and the time it takes to parse the returned xml document. The XML parsing in suds is rather slow. You can try http://docs.python-zeep.org/ which uses lxml for the parsing. (the performance issues was the reason why I created zeep)

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following table.
In short, you are taking the server workload into account, the server dosn't.

```
client                      server
start timing
client get (small data) ->  server receive request
                        <-  server ack request start timing
client receive ack
client waiting response     server workload to create response
                        <-  server response (big data)
client receive response
client ack response     ->  server stop timing
client workload parsing response
client stop timing
```

If you are able to start/stop timing at the **ack** points, your timing differences become lower.

Answer (score 0):

How about network latency, the time it takes for your query to reach the server and the time it takes for you to receive the answer back ?.
Did you do network tracing, usually you can see this cause in tcp headers timing of sending is stored, you could use network monitor (or its replacement), or wireshark. to analyze this.

A short simple latency test is pathping  on windows.